# Is there a terminology for 'making a struct inaccessible directly' in C?

Tags: c, struct

I've found a certain code in [hostap](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjTzP2WmoLTAhVBU7wKHcZZDdEQFggmMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fw1.fi%2F&usg=AFQjCNHw5Yvq0_sBkJyfipYvv4f5Uty6qw&sig2=buG4rmtPJC7fsQ0HLdW99A). The below is a simplified one:

## `a.h`

```
// it just declares 'there is a struct a'
struct a;

// it seems like an accessor to a private member b
int get_b(struct a);
```

## `a.c`

```
// definition is seprated from a header file
struct a {
    int b;
};

int get_b(struct a) {
    return a.b;
}
```

An object file `a.o` is generated with these two files.

And if other source codes want to use `struct a`, it cannot directly access to a member `b`, with a compiler complaining `dereferencing incomplete type`. I only can access to a member `b` with `get_b()`.

First time, I am very frustrated by such a pattern. But finally, I feel that it is very a well-designed pattern if someone wants to protect the integrity of `struct a` (e.g., values of memebers must be set in certain criteria, or members are dependent to each other so that change of one member will affect the others)

Is there a terminology for this kind of pattern?

Comment: You won't be able to include the file `a.h` in any other file because the compiler doesn't know how large `struct a` is and so can't call the function `get_b`.  You can change the code to have a pointer to a `struct a` because the compiler knows how large a pointer is and doesn't care how large the struct is.

Comment: [Opaque Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is referred to as an **opaque type**.  You know that a particular `struct` exists, but nothing else.

Because you know nothing about the contents of an opaque struct, you can't create an instance if it.  You can however create a *pointer* to it.

The example you give won't work because you would need to pass an instance of `struct a` to `get_b`, and you can't create an instance of `struct a`.  But if the function takes a pointer, you can do this:

```
int get_b(struct a *sa)
{
    return sa->b;
}
```

You'd also need a constructor-like function to create an instance, since an external module would be unable to do so:

```
struct a *create(int b)
{
    struct a *tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct a));
    tmp->b = b;
    return tmp;
}
```

Then your header would contain:

```
struct a;

int get_b(struct a *);
struct a *create(int);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29#An_information-hiding_mechanism), typically a component of Encapsulation.

As noted by dbush and dasblinkenlight, this specific instance would be an [opaque data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type).